# Java Perspective in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, perspective

[image]

Whenever I open Java perspective in Eclipse, it appears like the image.
Java EE perspective is totally fine.
Has anyone had the same problem and fixed it?

Comment: Do you have newest version of eclipse? What happens if you put eclipse from fullscreen->windowed?

Comment: Yes, I installed the latest version of Eclipse a few days ago. I put the Eclipse window from full screen to windowed but still have the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reset your perspective. With the `Java` perspective already selected go to

```
Window > Reset Perspective...
```

Comment: Does the issue persist after a restart? Does the area hidden respond to mouse-click events? Share as much details as possible. If you update these in your question would help others in helping you as well.